# Order Stacked Column Chart in Excel by values

Tags: excel

I was looking at the stacked column example here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/present-your-data-in-a-column-chart-HA010218663.aspx.

I wanted to know how I can re-arrange the 3-D column chart to show regional sales by descending order of total sales without modifying the excel sheet data.

Basically, how can I modify how the data is being displayed in the chart without making any external changes.

Comment: Please add more information on what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what your actual problem is. It is very unclear as-is...

Answer (score 0):

Although normally stacked bar charts are plotted as ranges they can be plotted cell by cell. Once you have decided the order (ie Southwest, Northwest etc in the linked example) the horizontal axis can be plotted as `=(Sheet1!$A$5,Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$A$4,Sheet1!$A$6,Sheet1!$A$3)` and each of the data series in the same way.